# How to have img same size as div

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I want to make a nav bar in the footer with images. The footer needs to be 10% of the total screen and the images need to be within those 10% as well. Only I don't get the images scale according to the screen size and are way bigger. What am I doing wrong?

I am using Bootstrap 4 and I intent to make a mobile version of my website but it is not displaying good.

```
<div class="footer navbar row">
 <div class="col-sm-2 menu_item">
<a href="#home" class="active"> 
    <img src="<source>" class="menu_img" alt="Logo"/>
</a>
 </div> 
 <div class="col-sm-2 menu_item">
<a href="#news">
<img src="<source>" class="menu_img" alt="Logo"/>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 menu_item">              
    <a href="#contact">
        <img src="<source>" class="menu_img" alt="Logo"/>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 menu_item">
  <a href="#contact">
    <img src="<source>" class="menu_img" alt="Logo"/>
   </a>
   </div>   
   <div class="col-sm-2 menu_item">
   <a href="#contact">
    <img src="<source>" class="menu_img" alt="Logo"/>
   </a>
   </div>
```

```
/* Place the navbar at the bottom of the page, and make it stick */ 
.navbar {
        background-color: var(--primary-color-1);
        overflow: hidden;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        height: 10vh;
    }
    /* Style the menu blocks */
    .menu_item {
        position: relative;
        padding: 2px 10px;
        margin: 0px;
    }
    /* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
    .navbar a {
        float: left;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;

    }
   /* Style the images/icons of the links */
    .menu_img {
        height:100%;
        width: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
      }
```

Comment: Have you tried using your browser's inspect ability (right click > inspect in Firefox) to trace exactly what css is setting the dimensions of your images?

Comment: Yes, I did, but that still didn't explain why it happened. But I have fixed it now :)

Answer (score 0):

responsive img's need width: 100%; to be responsive, you can control the image size with his container, for example:

```html
<div class="img-container">
    <img src="imgUrl"/>
</div>
```

```css
img{
    width: 100%;
}
.img-container{
    width: 10%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. My structure is like

```
<div class="footer">
  <div>
     <a>
       <img>
     </a>
   </div>
</div>
```

The footer div needs to be height:10%. But I need to set the height of all the other elements to 100%(which I didn't do before). Otherwise it will extend outside those. 'borders'